# "Eyeballing" complex derivative values using color domain plotting

Tags: complex-analysis

I am recently attempting to gain better intuition for complex functions by visualizing them using color domain plots.

One can view lines of constant phase as electric field lines, which always run along the gradient of the magnitude.

In this interpretation, the logarithmic derivative gives the electric field vector corresponding to a given 2D charge arrangement specified by a meromorphic function.

However, the only role I can find for the derivative itself is that it equals zero whenever the electric fields of all charges cancel (see the origin of the attached image).

Is there anyway to "eyeball" non-zero values of the complex derivative on color domain plots?

[image: Illustration of derivative = 0]

Comment: Being non-native english speaker/reader, I find it difficult to understand what you mean by "eyeballing". Any periphrase ?

Comment: To eyeball something is to know it by inspection, often only roughly.

Comment: What is the origin of the attached image? You need a plot legend corresponding to the different colors to determine the approximate values. A contour plot of $\Re(f(s))=0$ and $\Im(f(s))=0$ might be useful as the zeros of $f(s)$ are the intersections of these two contours, and everywhere else $f(s)\ne 0$. What is your definition of $f(s)$ (can you write a formula)?

Comment: Do you mean have simultaneously information about f'(z)/f(z) and about f'(z) ? I agree with Steven Clark : our question would be clearer if you say what is colored (a function connected to $z^3-1$ ?) and the color code you have used for the argument of this function (by placing a colorbar).